# Itemize without bullets

Tags: lists, itemize

I want to use the `itemize` environment exactly as it works by default, but hide the bullets that would otherwise appear.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You can do this in several ways: for example, by using an empty optional argument for `\item` (as **Jake** suggested), or by using the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to use an empty `label`, or by redefining `\labelitemi`; these approaches are illustrated in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[] First.
  \item[] Second.
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label={}]
  \item First.
  \item Second.
\end{itemize}

{\renewcommand\labelitemi{}
\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ``\begin{itemize}[label={}]`` doesn't work; ``\begin{itemize}[\label{}]`` does!

Comment: @PLG Sure? `\begin{itemize}[\label{}]` will trigger an error; on the other hand, `label={}` as an option to the environment (having loaded `enumitem`), suppresses the label, as required.

Comment: Using the MacTex environment, ``[label={}]`` produces ``label=`` as bullet symbol. Both ``[\label{}]`` and ``[\label={}]`` seem to produce the empty bullet symbol.

Comment: @PLG Can you please upload elsewhere (and provide a link in your next reply) a simple document producing the result you mention?

Comment: Using the http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago.zip template and
    ``\begin{itemize}[label={}]
    \item First.
    \item Second.
    \end{itemize}``
Results in an error. Using ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip results in the ``label=`` that I described above. Perhaps it is the class files, but then it would be good to have some clarification of what is going on. Thanks in advance for your effort! =)

Comment: Oh, I should add that the files are: ``llncs.dem`` in ``llncs2e.zip`` and ``doc/examples/cms-trad-sample.tex`` in ``biblatex-chicago.zip``.

Comment: This approach also works for nested itemize lists.

Comment: neither `label={}` nor `\label={}` allowed me to have math in the items, giving me "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

Answer (score 48):

Why do you want to use the `itemize` environment, if you don't want the bullets? You could simply use the `description` environment which seems to be exactly what you need. No hacking required.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
        \item Foo
        \item Bar
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The description environment introduces significantly more whitespace in front of each item though

Comment: @zakkak Agreed. This needs as much customisation as just customising the itemize environment.

Comment: This is imho the best answer, because if you don't have bullet points its not an enumeration but actually a description, imho.

Comment: With the `enumitem` package you can customize this solution for any whitespace to be exactly as you wish.

Answer (score 12):

The following also works. The `{}` specifies that nothing should be placed before the items. Use `\indent` as needed.

```
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[\indent {}]
        \item ABC
        \item ABC
        \item ABC
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. Does it require a particular package?

Comment: @jvriesem They might have meant to put `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the preamble of their MWE instead of `\usepackage{enumerate}`.

Comment: It works for me with `\usepackage{enumerate}`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use \null

```
\begin{itemize}[\null]
    \item First
    \item Second
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Are you using any packages that provides this interface? Also, why use `\null` when you can use `\relax` or `{}` or ... ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I also recommend a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for answers. Then it is easier to reproduce the result and the MWE shows the needed package(s).

Comment: You need to `\usepackage{enumitem}` as mentioned in the previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for an alternative solution: basically, you can pass anything in square brackets `\begin{itemize}[...]`

```
\begin{itemize}[x]
    \item First
    \item Second
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[  y]
    \item First
    \item Second
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[\qquad z]
    \item First
    \item Second
\end{itemize}
```

`\hspace{10pt}`, `\quad`, etc. commands can be used to add indentation.

[image]