# Suppress item numbers specifically in `enumerate` environment as modified by the package `enumitem`

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm trying to create a list or listlike structure that has the following characteristics:

- no extra vertical space between items
- no leading line numbers
- "looking nice" when surrounded by `\begin{multicols}{2}... \end{multicols}`.
- having no global or as few global effects on the document as possible.

It might be correct to use ordinary lines instead of a list, but I'm thinking of this region of text as a list *semantically* and I'd like to surface that in the structure of the LaTeX document.

The closest attempt at a solution that I've found (cobbled together from the TeX SE answers in **1001**) is:

```
% horrible hack!
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{}

\newenvironment{minimal_enumerate}%
{%
    \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-1ex}%
    \setlength{\partopsep}{1ex}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{1ex}%
}%
{%
    \end{enumerate}%
}%
```

Where blasting away `\theenumi` globally prevents the numbers `1, 2, 3` &c from being expressed, but still leaves a period that separates the would-be number from the list item.

Is there a way to modify the above definition so as to prevent the expression of list numbers or periods in front of items without global effects on the document?

*Ideally, is it possible to define an environment based on `enumerate` when the package `enumitem` is loaded and the package `enumerate` is not loaded?*

---

Here are some false starts I've had with other paths to a minimal list.

`short_itemize` is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136050).

```
\newenvironment{short_itemize}%
{%
    \begin{itemize}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}%
{%
    \end{itemize}%
}%
```

I can't figure out how to remove the bullets.

The other thing I've tried is just using `description` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397469).

But I can't figure out how to reduce the amount of spacing between items in the `description` without touching global configuration settings.

---

1001 -- consulted answers that appear to suggest `enumerate` as modified by the package `enumitem`.

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10689
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430559
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119935

Comment: If I understand well, you' like a ‘numberless enumerate’ – some kind of oxymoron?

Comment: It might be contrary to the intended meaning of `enumerate`, but the API of `enumerate` seems to expose most of the functionality I want. Ideally I'd like to define a new environment that's merely implemented in terms of `enumerate`. I included other potential solutions and where I hit a wall ... but `enumerate` seems to be the most flexible sequence-like environment I can find.

Comment: What I don't understand is this: what would be the difference with  a succession of ordinary paragraphs?