# Aligning formulas within itemize

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, itemize

I would like to write two equations side by side within a list (itemize).
I have tried as follows:

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item first item:
        \begin{align}
              x = y && a = b
        \end{align}
   \item second item:
        \begin{align}
           x = y1+x3+253+x && a = 3*b_1
        \end{align}
\end{itemize}
```

Between the two formulas I would like to write 'or' instead of leaving a blank space. And also, trying to align all of them (centering?).

Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: My idea is to use fixed tab stops. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558503/how-to-set-tab-stops-after-whitespaces-in-latex

Comment: Do you have other items without equations in this list?

Comment: only some text before using align

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein, how I could replace or (not the logic symbol, just characters) between the equations?

Comment: Would "\item [] or" work for you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50269/itemize-without-bullets

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43725.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility would be to mimic an itemize environment within `align*` or `alignat*` with \intertext:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\myintertext}[1]{\intertext{\makebox[\leftmargini][r]{\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep}}#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
   \item first item:
        \begin{align}
              x = y && a = b
        \end{align}
   \item second item:
        \begin{align}
           x = y1+x3+253+x && a = 3*b_1
        \end{align}
\end{itemize}

\begin{alignat}{3}
  \myintertext{first item}
x & =y & \makebox[4em]{or} & & a & = b \\
  \myintertext{second item}
           x & = y1+x3+253+x & \makebox[4em]{or} & & a & = 3*b_1
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Being the presence of `\hspace` into the enviroment `aligned`...all it has been done manually...If you change the formulas into the aligned you must set (with the eyes) the correct distance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
   \item first item:
        $\begin{aligned}[c]
         &\hspace{1.4cm} & x = y & \hspace{3.15cm} & a = b & \hspace{3.03cm} (1)
      \end{aligned}$
   \item second item: 
   $\begin{aligned}[c]
         & x = y1+x3+253+x & \hspace{1.33cm} & a = 3*b_1 & \hspace{1.9cm} (2)
      \end{aligned}$  
        \item third item:
         $\begin{aligned}[c]
         &\hspace{1.2cm} & x = y & \hspace{3.2cm} & a = b & \hspace{3cm} (3)
      \end{aligned}$  
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sebastiano, yes. But this should be already reproduced by the code provided. I would like to put 'or' between the two formulas in (1), similarly in (2) and (3). And whether possible, just for aesthetics, to center the formula in order to have a in (1), (2) and (3) almost aligned

Comment: @Math I think that the output (seem) to have the correct alignment :-)