# Horizontally list multiple tcolorbox

Tags: lists, tcolorbox, horizontal

I am using tcolorbox in order to create several boxes containing various words, to have sort of a Trait system, much like they do at [AoN](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=3) (see image below).
[image: AoNTraits]

The boxes are created as below:

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.90}

\newtcolorbox{TraitBox}{
    enhanced,
    size=tight,
    height=1.2em,
    leftrule=0.3mm,
    rightrule=0.3mm,
    left=0.5mm,
    right=0.5mm,
    top=0.3mm,
    bottom=0.3mm,
    coltext=white,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    colback=gray,
    colframe=light-gray,
    hbox}

\begin{TraitBox} Agile \end{TraitBox}
\begin{TraitBox} Finesse \end{TraitBox}
\begin{TraitBox} Thrown 10 Ft. \end{TraitBox}
\begin{TraitBox} Versatile S \end{TraitBox}
\begin{TraitBox} Invest \end{TraitBox}
```

Outputs:
[image: TraitBox as tcolorbox]

The desirable, and wanted, feature here is that the boxes are fitted to the width of the text.

However, I also would like for the boxes to be horizontally aligned, much like an inline list. Additionally, I want to use a foreach loop to simply list all the traits.

Attempts to make it an inline list, which include the foreach loop, has been making a raster:

```
\newcommand{\ListOfTraits}[1]{
    \begin{tcbraster}[ 
        raster before skip=0.5mm,
        raster after skip=0.5mm,
        % raster left skip=-0.5mm,
        raster columns=4, 
        % raster width=\textwidth -1pt,
        raster row skip = 0.5mm,
        raster equal height,
        enhanced,
        size=tight,
        leftrule=0.3mm,
        rightrule=0.3mm,
        % left=0.5mm,
        % right=0.5mm,
        top=0.3mm,
        bottom=0.3mm,% 
        coltext=white,
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        colback=gray,
        colframe=light-gray,
        ]
        \hspace{-1mm}
        \foreach \traits in {#1}{
        \begin{tcolorbox}\traits\end{tcolorbox}}
    \end{tcbraster}
}

\ListOfTraits{Agile,Finesse,Thrown 10 Ft.,Versatile S,Invest}
```

Output:
[image: Raster inline]

However, with a raster the width has to be defined by using columns. And as observed the box is no longer fitted to the width of the words. Additionally, with the trait "Thrown 10 Ft." this entry is too long for the column width and as such makes it two lines.

Thinking out of the box (hehe sorry), maybe placing the TraitBox in a list, taking inspiration from [Itemize without bullets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50269), but making it inline as presented by tom in the article [Inline lists in LaTeX using paralist](https://texblog.org/2013/02/01/inline-lists-in-latex-using-paralist/), forgoing the foreach loop for now:

```
\begin{inparadesc}
    \item[] \begin{TraitBox} Agile \end{TraitBox}
    \item[] \begin{TraitBox} Finesse \end{TraitBox}
    \item[] \begin{TraitBox} Thrown 10 Ft. \end{TraitBox}
    \item[] \begin{TraitBox} Versatile S \end{TraitBox}
    \item[] \begin{TraitBox} Invest \end{TraitBox}
\end{inparadesc}
```

However, this rendered the same result as before:
[image: inline list with TraitBox]

Anybody who has a solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Use `tcbox` rather and also check the manual 4.7.5 Size Shortcuts, has an almost identical example to your request.

Comment: You can also do ` \foreach \s in {word1,word2,wordd3,word4,word5,word6}{
\fcolorbox{white}{red!5!white}{\s}}`  without tcolorbox but still need the tikz pkg

Comment: Thanks! I'll try ASAP